# Impredicativity and set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, philosophy

I have thought about an example in set theory, but I don't know if its legal to do it, maybe someone can help. Let $\emptyset$ be given and let $A$ be a non empty set.
Let us create the subset $X = \{x \in A, x \in \emptyset\}$. It appears that $X = \emptyset$, thus we have an impredicative definition $\emptyset = \{x \in A, x \in \emptyset\}$ which is quite weird.

Indeed, if $X$ is non empty, $\forall x \in X$,  $x \in A \wedge x \in \emptyset$, is always false. That is, $\exists x \in X$, $x \notin A \vee x \notin \emptyset$, but if such $x$ is in $X$, then clearly $x \in A \wedge x \in \emptyset$ so the proposition is false. Hence contradiction, $X$ is non empty being false, $X$ is empty by LEM.

Note that we could have also put $X = \{ x \in \emptyset, x \notin \emptyset\}$, and we would have obtained another impredicative definition. Does set theory/FOL language allows it ? How comes it's possible ?

Comment: I don't see how the definition of $X$ is impredicative.

Comment: See [Predicative and Impredicative Definitions](http://www.iep.utm.edu/predicat/)

Comment: "It appears that X=∅, thus we have an impredicative definition ∅={x∈A,x∈∅}" ... It is **not** a definition of the *emptyset*, because you have "used it" already into : X={x∈A,x∈∅}.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of axioms is perfect. Set theory does allow it, one thing you cannot do is define a set using a formula in wich the set occurs in it, but that is not the case. You defined a new set $X$ and proved (via extensionality) that it is equal to the emptyset.

In fact, in the presence of axiom of infinity, axiom of empty set is unnecessary

$\emptyset = \{ x \in \omega \ | \ x \notin \omega\}$

or

$\emptyset = \{x \in \omega \ | \ x \neq x\}$

Comment: Ah, so even if I defined this set that **appears** to be the same as in its definition, its not considered impredicative while ZF use extensively extensionality ? It's as if impredicativity was only syntaxical ?

Comment: Yes, because if you add this new symbol $\emptyset$ in ZF language you'll add with a new axiom for the symbol (the axiom for its definition), and you would only possibly use it in the defining sentence if it would already a part of your theory, which is not the case. after the definiton you can make such assertments, as long as the definition is not circular.

Comment: I understand, but I find it quite weird to think of impredicativity as something purely syntaxical, considering equality is extensional in ZF. For example, because $X = \emptyset$, my definition is equivalent (not to say equal) to $X = \{x \in A, x \in X\}$ which is clearly impredicative in your sense.

Comment: I don't see as an impredicativity as its not a self-reference definition @sure. It's only a self-reference statement.

Comment: What is a definition then ? Is it something purely syntaxic ?